# Unable to close a short sell position in Fidelity even after buying the the stock

Tags: shorting-securities

I performed a SHORT SELL for MRNA stock sometime back and then performed a BUY to cover the SHORT. Even after many days of buying the stock I still see the SHORT position in my Fidelity portfolio. I performed both SHORT and BUY in Margin account. Has someone faced this issue or can suggest a solution for this?
Just in case if it helps further clarify the situation. I already had some stock of MRNA when I did a SHORT SELL.
Thanks in advance!

[image: Short and Buy stock details]

Comment: Opposing trades in the same security should offset and disappear.  Contact your broker.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I tried reaching out to Fidelity customer care for the first time and seems like they just have the contact details for name sake and no one to respond to email, chat or call.

Comment: I don't know if that's Fidelity's usual MO or if they too have been caught up in this GameStop menagerie - Schwab and Vanguard (and perhaps others) have had log on issues and at times, the phones have been jammed.

Comment: I waited for about 3.5 hours on the call being moved through 3 of Fidelity experts but once I was able to talk to the correct person it was resolved from their side in 5 minutes.